# How to get sequelize -auto to generate autoincrement on model from mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, sequelize-auto

I have a languages tabel in mysql db where I have an Id that is autoincremented:

```
CREATE TABLE `languages` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Language` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

When I run my sequelize-auto command:

```
sequelize-auto -h 127.0.0.1 -d DBNAME -u root -x PASSWORD -p 3306 --dialect mysql -c MYPATH\json/sequelize-auto-settings.json -o MODELSPATH\src\assets\models
```

I get the following modeL:

```
/* jshint indent: 1 */

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('languages', {
        Id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            field: 'Id'
        },
        Language: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'Language'
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'languages'
    });
};
```

Why am I missing the `autoincrment : true` on the Id field ?

I can add it manually but it defeates the purpose of using sequelize -auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took some time and I can honstly say I still dont know what the issue was.

I solved it by installing  [sequelize-auto v3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-auto-v3)  and then it worked as intended.

Comment: There have been many updates to `sequelize-auto` recently, so it should be ahead of the "v3" package now.